# Date type in Powershell ConvertTo-JSON

Tags: json, powershell, timestamp, dhcp

In Powershell, if I obtain DHCP leases from a server using `Get-DHCPServerv4Lease` and then convert that to JSON, here is an example output:

```
....
"LeaseExpiryTime" : "\/Date(1457009853298)\/",
....
```

**My question: What is that date number?** Its not Unix timestamp or Windows filetime.

```
Unix TS:          Thursday, October 20, 48140 11:14:58pm
Windows Filetime: Tuesday, January 2, 1601 4:28:21pm
```

The lease expiry time in the DHCP console is `3/3/2016 7:57:33 AM EST`. The best I've been able to come up with is chopping off the last three digits, which turns it into a proper Unix timestamp and gives me the correct time in UTC (my TZ is EST).

Of course, if I `ConvertFrom-Json` I get a proper `DateTime` object, albeit in UTC rather than EST:

```
$data | ConvertFrom-JSON
....
LeaseExpiryTime : 3/3/2016 12:57:33 PM
```

I can't seem to make a correct date using `Get-Date` or even any methods in `[DateTime]::` using that '1457009853298'

Running `Get-Date | Convertto-JSON` gives me the below, but I still don't know what I can do with that value.

```
{
"value":  "\/Date(1456939716572)\/",
"DisplayHint":  2,
"DateTime":  "Wednesday, March 2, 2016 12:28:36 PM"
}
```

Comment: [See TheMadTechnician's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26068643/3905079) in the linked question.

Comment: Thank you @briantist! Apparently I need to work on my searching skills.

Comment: I typically can't find duplicates with SO's search and end up finding them in google while researching the question!

Comment: Also these had more information related to my use:
[Format a Microsoft JSON date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)

[JSON PHP Format Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749778/php-date-format-date1365004652303-0500)